# WooCommerce: change display order of product short description and price

Tags: hooks, woocommerce-offtopic, child-theme

I'd like to move the price "$4.99–$24.99" below the product short description "Seriously. Drink a cup of this..."

**NSFW Image Below ( Adult Language )**

> [image]

Any ideas how to do this?  I already have a child theme, but I'm not sure what WooCommerce file needs to be overridden.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If you look at `woocommerce/templates/content-single-product.php` you'll see that the product summary is constructed using hooks with different priorities.

Here's the relevant section:

```
    <?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_single_product_summary hook
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_title - 5
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_rating - 10
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_price - 10
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_excerpt - 20
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart - 30
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_meta - 40
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_sharing - 50
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' );
    ?>
```

The price has a priority of 10, the excerpt has a priority of 20. To swap them around, change the priorities by modifying the actions in your child theme's `functions.php`.

Like this:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );

remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20 );


add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 10 );

add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 20 );
```

Comment: You ROCK! Thanks for the awesome explanation and solution :)